# Iteratively removing a fraction of a set

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I am stuck with a problem, where I end up with a situation where I iteratively remove an $\delta/\epsilon$ fraction of a set. I have some set $X$ given and start start by removing $\delta/\epsilon|X|$ many elements. From the resulting set $|X^\prime|$ I again remove $\delta/\epsilon|X^\prime|$ many elements and so on. Moreover, I do this $1/\epsilon$ many times. Here $\epsilon>0$ is fixed an I want to find some $\delta$ such that the total portion I have removed after $1/\epsilon$ iterations is less than $\epsilon$.
I pictured that the iterations give me a sum of the form
$$\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}\left(1-\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}\left(1-\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}\left(\dots\right)\right)\right)$$
and expanding this leads to
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{1}{\epsilon}} (-1)^{i-1}\left(\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}\right)^i$$
I tried to separate this sum and used the formula for the geometric series to get a simpler expression, but it got kind of ugly. So I was wondering if I did something wrong or if there is an easier way to see how big the total removed portion will be. As already stated a simple upper bound would be fantastic.

Does any one have a tip?

Best regards and many thanks in advance!

Comment: You say you are removing $\epsilon/\delta$ of the elements each time, but from the math your wrote, it seems like you are removing $\delta/\epsilon$ each time. Which is it?

Comment: It's $\delta/\epsilon$. Sorry for the mistake. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You are making the iteration formula way too complicated.

Starting from $X\newcommand{\d}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\e}{\delta}$, let $X'$ be the result of removing $\e/\d$ items from $X$. THen
$$
|X'|=|X|-\frac\e\d|X|=\left(1-\frac\e\d\right)|X|
$$
Now, when we remove items from $X'$ to get $X''$, we have
$$
|X''|=|X'|-\frac\e\d|X'|=\left(1-\frac\e\d\right)|X'|=\left(1-\frac\e\d\right)^2|X|
$$
The pattern persists. After $k$ iterations, the number of items remaining is
$$
\left(1-\frac\e\d\right)^k|X|
$$
You want the fraction of items removed after $k=1/\epsilon$ rounds to be less than $\epsilon$. Therefore, you just need to solve for $\delta$ in
$$
\left(1-\frac\e\d\right)^{1/\epsilon}<\epsilon
$$